# 1-D Heat Equation, bounding difference in $\alpha$ given surface temperature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

Given the following heat equation and boundary conditions:

$u_t= \alpha(x) u_{xx}, \quad x \geqslant 0 \,\,\text{and}\,\, \exists b \geqslant a > 0, a  \leqslant  \alpha(x)  \leqslant  b\\
u_x(0,t) = \begin{cases} 1 , \quad 0  \leqslant  t  \leqslant  t_h \\ 
0 ,\quad  t_h < t  \leqslant  t_f \end{cases} \\
u(x,0)=0$

It seems that distinct $\alpha(x)$ could give rise to distinct $u(x,t)$. However, if only two identical surface heat responses $u_1(0,t) = u_2(0,t)$ are observed over the same time interval $[0, t_f]$, is it possible to derive a bound around the difference between $\alpha_1(x)$ and $\alpha_2(x)$(or $\int_{x} |\alpha_1(x) - \alpha_2(x)|dx$) in terms of $a$, $b$, $t_h$ and $t_f$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An evident one is $|\alpha_1(x)-\alpha_2(x)|\le b-a$.